# Laravel 7 Route Group return 404 on some related routes

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing, laravel-7

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'cart'], function (){

    Route::get('', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
    Route::get('{id}', 'CartController@create')->name('cart.create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::any('update/{id}/{qty}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::any('saveorder', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::any('delete/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('item.delete')->middleware('auth');
    Route::any('empty', 'CartController@empty')->name('cart.empty')->middleware('auth');

});
```

Some of the routes still works but some of them are broken and returning 404 even that the routes exist

the broken routes are :   item.delete    ,     cart.empty   ,     cart.store

```
      | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | cart                    | cart.index       | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@index                              | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | cart/delete/{rowId}     | item.delete      | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@destroy                            | web        |
|        |                                        |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | cart/empty              | cart.empty       | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@empty                              | web        |
|        |                                        |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST                                   | cart/saveorder          | cart.store       | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@store                              | web        |
|        |                                        |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | PUT                                    | cart/update/{id}/{qty}  | cart.update      | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@update                             | web        |
|        |                                        |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | cart/{id}               | cart.create      | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@create                             | web        |
|        |                                        |                         |                  |
```

Comment: run this `php artisan route:list` and show me route list

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a GET method with `cart.empty` and `cart.store` then they will be handled by `cart.create`, you should put those routes first (order matters), also its better to be explicit with the route methods instead of using `Route::any`

```
Route::prefix('cart')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
    Route::any('saveorder', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
    Route::any('empty', 'CartController@empty')->name('cart.empty');
    Route::any('delete/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('item.delete');
    Route::any('update/{id}/{qty}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
    Route::get('{id}', 'CartController@create')->name('cart.create');
});
```

Comment: when declaring other methods  instead of using the any one  i got errors like the 'method' method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: 'other method'.

Comment: you need to send the appropriate method from your frontend: for blade you can use @method('PUT') for example, or if you're using an http client like axios then you can use axios.put()...

Comment: but i am working with href's there is no forms used , the set of cart routes were working , they became broken just when i grouped them .

Comment: just because a piece of code is working doesn't mean its good code, HTTP methods are there for a reason, you should send the appropriate method from the frontend and accept the right method in your routes instead of using GET for everything. I suggest you read on HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cart', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'CartController@create')->name('cart.create');
    Route::any('/update/{id}/{qty}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
    Route::any('/saveorder', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
    Route::any('/delete/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('item.delete');
    Route::any('/empty', 'CartController@empty')->name('cart.empty');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::prefix('cart')->group(function (){
  Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('{id}', 'CartController@create')->name('cart.create');
    Route::put('update/{id}/{qty}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
    Route::post('saveorder', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
    Route::delete('delete/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('item.delete');
    Route::post('empty', 'CartController@empty')->name('cart.empty');
  });
  Route::get('/', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
});
```

Two things to consider. Your `cart.index` could potentially match URI's underneath the route. For security, please try not to use `Route::any` if possible. As explained in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing. As @Sobir suggests, run `php artisan route:list` and see your actual list of routes as Laravel sees it.

If something is missing or ambiguous, you may have to reconsider some route parameters to avoid confusion. Or regroup them in different ways. Your route list will certainly grow. Anticipate on what you're planning in the future of what you are building.

Comment: the routes were working before i grouped them , after that grouping i got three of them broken , so there is no problem after i checked thr routing list , ps: i just put the routing list above ^^^^^